# How can i change the `git difftool` "change line" color?

Tags: linux, console, difftool, securecrt

I spend lots of hours a day working in linux consoles. As my work station has a Windows 10 OS, i use SecureCRT which works perfect. I use the "Solarized Dracula" color scheme in SecureCRT.

As i also develop software i use the `git difftool` command multiple times a day and i'm realy fustrated about the used colors for the changed lines and changes themselve. The changed lines are highlighted (which is fine so i see the changes in one glance) in almost the same color as the text (white/grey) and the change themselve is highlighted in exactly the same color as the highlight (red).

How can i make the highlight much more transparant or if thats not possible, change the color of it? I don't want to change the colors for my whole console! I tried to find a solution via Google as its a common issue i guess but can't find a clear explanation or solution.

Note: I also tried different (SecureCRT) color shemes but they all have the same (or similar) issue.

[image]

Comment: That's not a git problem. `difftool` is using a user-configured external diff tool (as opposed to `git diff`). What tool do you have configured? Check your `.gitconfig`.

Comment: I don't have content in my `~/.gitconfig`. I allways use `git difftool` or `git difftool a b`. I think it uses `Vim` under the hood as i use commands like `:qa!` to close the diff screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `git config` commands might help. Examples:

```
git config --global color.diff.old "red normal bold"
git config --global color.diff.new "green normal bold"
```

References:

- [8.1 Customizing Git - Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)
- [How can I reset to the default color scheme #259](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/259)
- [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy)